# How to sort arrays in fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I want to create a function to sort an array of for example strings.

[This](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Array.ts.html#sortby) seems to outline the way, but as so often, I struggle with understanding the documentation.

#### So my questions are:

- What is `Ord` doing?
- What is `contramap` doing?
- How to then build this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is Ord doing?

`Ord` -  element which implements `Ord` can be ordered and compared. See [fp-ts Ord docs](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Ord.ts.html#ord-overview) and [rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) for more information

This is how it is implemented:

```js
export declare type Ordering = -1 | 0 | 1

export interface Ord<A> {
  readonly compare: (second: A) => (self: A) => Ordering
}
```

`N` is a namespace which includes utilities for working with numbers.

> What is contramap doing?

Please see the [article](https://dev.to/gcanti/getting-started-with-fp-ts-ord-5f1e) of fp-ts creator `Giulio Canti`. `contramap` is a [combinator](https://dev.to/gcanti/functional-design-combinators-14pn)

> The goal of a combinator is to create new "things" from previously defined "things".

In this case, `contramap` reducec object to the element which is comparable

---

> How to then build this function?

If you have an array of strings, you can get rid of `pipe`:

```js
import { sortBy } from 'fp-ts/Array'
import * as S from 'fp-ts/string'

const sortByNameByAge = sortBy([S.Ord])

const persons = ['c','b']

console.log(sortByNameByAge(persons)) // b, c
```

Comment: Nice, thank you for linking the article